# Horizontal analysis by generating list using while-loop

Tags: list, python-2.7, while-loop

Given the following list of list:

[[0.074, 0.073, 0.072, 0.03, 0.029, 0.024, 0.021, 0.02], [0.02, 0.02, 0.015], [0.026, 0.026, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.015], [0.021, 0.021, 0.02, 0.017], [0.077, 0.076, 0.074, 0.055, 0.045, 0.021], [0.053, 0.052, 0.051, 0.023, 0.022], [0.016, 0.016]]

How could I cycle through the list and pull out #1 from each of the sub-list, #2 from each of the sub-list and #3 from each of the sub-list and produce separate lists.

For example, #1 should include 0.074, 0.02, 0.026, 0.021, 0.077, 0.063 and 0.016 in this case. And they will be in a separate stand-alone list.

I used the while loop but it didn't work for me:

```
a=0
b=len(data['stock'])

while a<=b - 1:
    print data['stock'][a][0]
            a = a + 1
    print "\n"


while a<=b - 1:
    print data['stock'][a][1]
        a = a + 1
print "\n"

while a<=b - 1:
    print data['stock'][a][2]
        a = a + 1
print "\n"

while a<=b - 1:
    print data['stock'][a][3]
        a = a + 1
print "\n"

while a<=b - 1:
    print data['stock'][a][4]
        a = a + 1
print "\n"

while a<=b - 1:
    print data['stock'][a][5]
        a = a + 1
print "\n"

while a<=b - 1:
    print data['stock'][a][6]
        a = a + 1
print "\n"
```

How many I solve this problem and create lists based on the above logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to transpose lists is to use `zip`:

```
>>> data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> zip(*data)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

To get around the problem that your data isn't consistently shaped, you could use `izip_longest`:

```
>>> data = [[0.074, 0.073, 0.072, 0.03, 0.029, 0.024, 0.021, 0.02], [0.02, 0.02, 0.015], [0.026, 0.026, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.015], [0.021, 0.021, 0.02, 0.017], [0.077, 0.076, 0.074, 0.055, 0.045, 0.021], [0.053, 0.052, 0.051, 0.023, 0.022], [0.016, 0.016]]
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> izip_longest(*data)
<itertools.izip_longest object at 0x101d77c00>
>>> list(izip_longest(*data))
[(0.074, 0.02, 0.026, 0.021, 0.077, 0.053, 0.016), (0.073, 0.02, 0.026, 0.021, 0.076, 0.052, 0.016), (0.072, 0.015, 0.02, 0.02, 0.074, 0.051, None), (0.03, None, 0.02, 0.017, 0.055, 0.023, None), (0.029, None, 0.02, None, 0.045, 0.022, None), (0.024, None, 0.015, None, 0.021, None, None), (0.021, None, None, None, None, None, None), (0.02, None, None, None, None, None, None)]
```

and thus:

```
>>> columns = list(izip_longest(*data))
>>> columns[0]
(0.074, 0.02, 0.026, 0.021, 0.077, 0.053, 0.016)
>>> columns[1]
(0.073, 0.02, 0.026, 0.021, 0.076, 0.052, 0.016)
>>> columns[2]
(0.072, 0.015, 0.02, 0.02, 0.074, 0.051, None)
```

I'm not sure what you want to do for "#3" -- your last sublist only has two elements.  `izip_longest` has a `fillvalue` option you can use to specify what to do, which defaults to `None` (which is why the last entry in `columns[2]` is `None`).

Comment: This is very cool. How would you deal the situation where there is a duplicate value within the list. For example, if you look at list #7 where the elements are 0.016 and 0.016. They would both be rank #1 but the code would treat them as separate item. Is there a way to get rid of the duplicate price within each sub-list before doing the horizontal list building?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `itemgetter`:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> map(itemgetter(0), data)
[0.074, 0.02, 0.026, 0.021, 0.077, 0.053, 0.016]
>>> map(itemgetter(1), data)
[0.073, 0.02, 0.026, 0.021, 0.076, 0.052, 0.016]
```

You could also use a list comprehension (which is probably more readable):

```
>>> [l[0] for l in data]
[0.074, 0.02, 0.026, 0.021, 0.077, 0.053, 0.016]
```